# When n = 5 , Why is " Done! " part printed 5 times even though it is after the recursive call statement?

Tags: c++, recursion

I understand why "I am Calculating" part is printed 5 times since its above the call statement. Shouldn't the "Done!" part only be printed once after the five lines of "I am calculating" being printed and then f be returned?

```
int factorial( int n)
{
    cout<<"I am calculating F("<<n<<")\n ";
    if(n == 0)
        return 1 ;
    int f = n * factorial(n - 1);
    cout<<"Done! F("<<n<<") = " <<f<<'\n';
    return f;  
}

int main()
{
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  int result = factorial(n);
  cout << result;  
}

CODE OUTPUT:
5
I am calculating F(5)
 I am calculating F(4)
 I am calculating F(3)
 I am calculating F(2)
 I am calculating F(1)
 I am calculating F(0)
 Done! F(1) = 1
Done! F(2) = 2
Done! F(3) = 6
Done! F(4) = 24
Done! F(5) = 120
120
```

Comment: Every recursive call will also return and so will also print the "Done" text (apart from the call with n=0.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `factorial` 6 times in total, and only 1 of those times the `if(n == 0)` is true and the `return 1` is executed (before `DONE` gets printed), the other 5 times it runs to completion until `return f`!

That's exactly how it is expected.

- `main()` prints `5`
- `main()` calls `factorial(5)`

  - `factorial(5)` prints `I am calculating F(5)`
  - `factorial(5)` calls `factorial(4)`

    - `factorial(4)` prints `I am calculating F(4)`
    - `factorial(4)` calls `factorial(3)`

      - `factorial(3)` prints `I am calculating F(3)`
      - `factorial(3)` calls `factorial(2)`

        - `factorial(2)` prints `I am calculating F(2)`
        - `factorial(2)` calls `factorial(1)`

          - `factorial(1)` prints `I am calculating F(1)`
          - `factorial(1)` calls `factorial(0)`

            - `factorial(0)` prints `I am calculating F(0)`
            - Since `n` is `0` now, `factorial(0)` returns `1` to `factorial(1)`
          - `factorial(1)` sets `f` to `1 * 1` with the second `1` coming back from the `factorial(0)` call
          - `factorial(1)` prints `Done! F(1) = 1`
          - `factorial(1)` returns `1` to `factorial(2)`
        - `factorial(2)` sets `f` to `2 * 1` with the `1` coming back from the `factorial(1)` call
        - `factorial(2)` prints `Done! F(2) = 2`
        - `factorial(2)` returns `2` to `factorial(3)`
      - `factorial(3)` sets `f` to `3 * 2` with the `2` coming back from the `factorial(2)` call
      - `factorial(3)` prints `Done! F(3) = 6`
      - `factorial(3)` returns `6` to `factorial(4)`
    - `factorial(4)` sets `f` to `4 * 6` with the `6` coming back from the `factorial(3)` call
    - `factorial(4)` prints `Done! F(4) = 24`
    - `factorial(4)` returns `24` to `factorial(5)`
  - `factorial(5)` sets `f` to `5 * 24` with the `24` coming back from the `factorial(4)` call
  - `factorial(5)` prints `Done! F(5) = 120`
  - `factorial(5)` returns `120` to `main()`
- `main()` prints `120` with the `120` coming back from the `factorial(5)` call

Comment: Yeeeeah... I'm glad it was just `5` not `99`.

Comment: Then we'd have to explain a different question, namely why the result is garbage, coming from the fact that the number `99!` has 156 decimal digits and surely won't fit into an `int` of any bitness commonly in use nowadays. :D

Comment: Loved the explanation. Clean and concise! I would have up voted if I could!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the recursive call in your code does not terminate the execution of the calling function.

`return` is only after the `print it out` part.

Therefore every invocation of the function, top-level or deeper, prints the text, just before returning the result to the caller, much in the same way as it is printing "I am calculating" every time.

Try finding some way to detect that the current execution is either on the top-level, or the-most-deepest invocations, and simply add an `if` to print out the 'Done' only in this case.

EDIT: or just move the 'print "Done"' out from the  `factorial` and move it into `main`, after call to `factorial`..

Answer (score 0):

> I understand why "I am Calculating" part is printed 5 times

You are wrong. This text is outputted `6` times for numbers 0 - 5 inclusively.

This statement

```
cout<<"Done! F("<<n<<") = " <<f<<'\n';
```

is executed 5 times because when n is equal to 0 the function exits.

```
if(n == 0)
    return 1 ;
```

That is for n equal to 0 the statement does not get the control.

Comment: Oops, i meant to type 6. Sorry.